# How to discard changes in Rules module

Tags: rules

Depending on a condition I want a node's changed content not to be overwritten on the old content. That is old content should be retained and new one discarded so that node does not change.

Which action should I add?
I've tried many but everytime a user saves a node, it is permanently changing the node's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a rule for the "Content is going to be saved" event, and add a "Execute custom PHP code" action.
The code you write have access to some variables by reference: `$node`, `$node_unchanged`, `$user`, `$author`, `$author_unchanged`, and `$user`.

For example, you can use the following code to set the title as it was before the node was  edited.

```
$node->title = $node_unchanged->title;

return array('node' => $node);
```

[image: screenshot]

Similar code is usable in the version for Drupal 7 of the Rules module; what changes is the variables to which the code has access.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: but how do I revert to it's old content in the body? I don't find anything like $node->body

Comment: The old content of the body should be in `$node_unchanged->body`; if that is not available (but I would be surprised if it were not), then you can load the unchanged node using `node_load($node_unchanged->nid)`.

Comment: Thanks, there is another way I found: redirect to another url and display error message. This can discard the changes as well.

Comment: @AgA I did the redirect and the message without the PHP and it didn't work for me. Any extra step or config?

Comment: @redhatlab I don't remember having done anything else than simply redirecting.